# Podfile issues when attempting to share dependencies between a core framework, app and share extension

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

**Backstory**: My pods were all working fine when I had a single app depending on external libraries, but I am having issues after adding in a share extension.

To share my dependencies and core code between app and extension, I pulled out core code into a separate Cocoa Touch framework. However, I am now having issues with my pod dependencies.

[image]

---

Through trial and error, I have come across various issues:

1. *Pod installation error*: [!] The 'XXX' target has frameworks with conflicting names: alamofire, gtmsessionfetcher, googletoolboxformac, kingfisher, mixpanel, protobuf, realm, realmswift, result, rxcocoa, rxswift, swiftyjson, and nanopb.
2. *No such module error*: Pods install successfully, but I get this error for external pod dependencies in app extension
3. *Crash*: Everything looks like it has installed, but during runtime, I get a crash due to multiple versions of dependencies being installed and the app switching between the versions.

---

How should I structure my Podfile to:

- share some pods (e.g. RxSwift/RxCocoa) between Core, App and Extension targets
- keep some pods (e.g. Alamofire) only in Core target
- keep some pods (e.g. Mixpanel-swift) only in App + Extension targets

**Current Podfile attempt**:
https://gist.github.com/yahmad/ccc3cd0d882dabd3c76622e45cfe90eb

Comment: I have attempted everything from abstract_target usage to explicitly referencing the pods in separate target sections, but no dice as yet :(